# How to union properly using left joins

Tags: mariadb

I have multiple unions i have to perform to get a value the breaks up over time. So the fields i have are: CustomerName, CustomerID, 2017Q1, 2017Q3, 2017Q4. Each Quarter is in a different table, so i created a view that unions all of them together: Customer Name, CustomerID, Quarter (REUP Score) and YQ '20XXQX'. I am having a hard time grouping everything together as it keeps showing me multiple rows for the same ID.

I have tried doing a union ALL and performing left joins and most recently i created a master view will all the tables in one view and now i am trying to pivot the data, so i can get 1 row for each CustomerName, CustomerID, '2017Q1', '2017Q3', '2017Q4', ect.

```
SELECT
`2017Q1`.`customerInputName` AS `CustomerInputName`,
`2017Q1`.`customerInputCustid` AS `customerInputCustid`,
`2017Q1`.`REUP` AS `Quarter`,
'2017Q1' AS `YQ` 
FROM
`ACC1_2017Q1` `2017Q1` UNION ALL
SELECT
`2017Q3`.`customerInputName` AS `CustomerInputName`,
`2017Q3`.`customerInputCustid` AS `customerInputCustid`,
`2017Q3`.`REUP` AS `Quarter`,
'2017Q3' AS `YQ` 
FROM
`ACC1_2017Q3` `2017Q3` UNION ALL
SELECT
`2017Q4`.`customerInputName` AS `CustomerInputName`,
`2017Q4`.`customerInputCustid` AS `customerInputCustid`,
`2017Q4`.`REUP` AS `Quarter`,
'2017Q4' AS `YQ` 
FROM
`ACC1_2017Q4` `2017Q4`
group by 
    `CustomerInputName`,
    `customerInputCustid`,
```

RESULTS:

```
customerInputName    CustomerInputCustID    2017Q1   2017Q3   2017Q4
AMANDA               113345038               657     NULL     NULL
AMANDA               113345038               NULL    NULL     684
```

DESIRED RESULTS:

```
customerInputName    CustomerInputCustID    2017Q1   2017Q3   2017Q4
AMANDA               113345038               657     NULL     684
```

Comment: This is an example of why not to make identical tables for different time periods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your query like this:

```
select 
  t.customerInputName, t.CustomerInputCustID, 
  max(t.2017Q1) 2017Q1, max(t.2017Q3) 2017Q3, max(t.2017Q4) 2017Q4
from (
  <your query here>
) t
group by t.customerInputName, t.CustomerInputCustID
```